# Is $\frac{|C\cap B_r(x)|}{|B_r(x)|}$ decreasing in $r$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $C$ is a measurable set, $x\in C$,  is
$$
\frac{|C\cap B_r(x)|}{|B_r(x)|}
$$
decreasing in $r$? Or any counterexamples?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

@user39992 and @Karolis Juodelė show that it can not hold for all $x\in C$. Then I change my question: is
$$
\frac{|C\cap B_r(x)|}{|B_r(x)|}
$$
decreasing in $r$ for almost all $x\in C$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $C$ be a ball and let $x$ be a point on it's boundary. Observe that as $r$ approaches $0$, $\frac{|C\cap B_r(x)|}{|B_r(x)|}$ increases, approaching $\frac 1 2$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take the family of concentric annuli with $0$; $\{2^{-2n-1}<x<2^{-2n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$. Then choosing $x=0$, you'll see that the the ratios will oscillate.